# Let $z$ be a complex number satisfying $|z|^4-16|z|^2-3(z^2+{\overline{z}}^2)+9=0$ ..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, maxima-minima

> Let $z$ be a complex number satisfying $$|z|^4-16|z|^2-3(z^2+{\bar {z}}^2)+9=0$$ and let $\min(|z|)=a,b=\max(|z|)$ then find $ab$.

---

We notice that $$\Im(z^2+{\overline{z}}^2)=0$$
$$\Im({(z+\overline{z})}^2-2z\bar z)=0$$ but this is obvious as both $z+\bar z,z \bar z$ are real.
Hence i was unable to find any additional condition

Also substituition $z=x+iy$ and taking $x^2=l,y^2=m$ we have the mess $$l^2+m^2-22l+10m+2lm+9=0$$I recognise this as a quadratic and setting $D\ge 0$  may give the max and min value of $l+m$.

But surely there must be something easier?!

Comment: Consider writing $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then the resulting equation is a quadratic in $r^2$.

Comment: @preferred_anon but even that  becomes pretty messy, i  thoght there might be a geometrical interpretation to this problem

Comment: If you want to follow your approach, discriminant will not help, but finding extrema using Lagrange multipliers would work. Probably better to recognise that the equation is simply $|z^2-3|^2=16|z|^2$ or $|z^2-3|=4|z|$ and use that though to find extrema of $f(z)=|z|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let $t = z^2$, so that we can rewrite that as
$$|t|^2-16|t| - 3(t+\overline t) + 9 = 0 \iff (|t| - 8)^2 = 3(t + \overline t) + 55$$

Now it may be easier to note that $|t|$ can find extrema when $\Im(t)=0$, so that we may consider only the case $t \in \mathbb R$.  So we have for extreme $|t| = k$, the quadratic:
$$k^2 -22k +9 = 0 \implies |t|_\min \cdot |t|_\max = 9$$
Hence $a\cdot b = \sqrt{9}=3$